# In postgresql return result of a function in a rule when performing INSERT INTO RETURNING

Tags: function, postgresql, insert, sql-returning

I have a View that has several fields.

When i `INSERT INTO` a view I run a function based on `INSERT` parametrs. The function returns a value.

How can I retrieve The value from rule?

`INSERT RETURNING` Gives me:

> ERROR:  cannot perform INSERT RETURNING on relation "full_subntes"
>   HINT:   You need an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule with a RETURNING clause.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    a VARCAHR primary key,
    b VARCHAR,
);

CREATE VIEW test_v AS SELECT * FROM test;

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE Test_v_Insert AS ON INSERT TO Test_v
DO INSTEAD (
    SELECT myFunction('param');
);

INSERT INTO test_v(a, b) VALUES ('a', 'b') RETURNING a, b;
```

Then I get an error described above.

Comment: Could you please post the whole view definition, the operations you perform and the desired resultset?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example.

First, we create a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a integer, b varchar, primary key (a));
```

Then, we create a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_view AS SELECT * FROM test;
```

Next, the update rule is created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE rl_test_view_update AS
    ON UPDATE TO test_view DO INSTEAD
    UPDATE test SET a = NEW.a, b = NEW.b
    WHERE test.a = old.a AND test.b = old.b;
```

And finally, here is the insert rule:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE rl_test_view_insert AS
    ON INSERT TO test_view DO INSTEAD
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (NEW.a, NEW.b)
    RETURNING test.*;
```

Now you can insert some test data:

```
INSERT INTO test_view (a, b) VALUES (1,'John Doe') RETURNING a;
```

and check the tuples inserted:

```
SELECT * FROM test_view;
```

Comment: I need to run a function value of with will be returned inside an insert rule.
Simple insert returning woks fine.

Answer (score -1):

In order to update a view in Postgres, you need to define a rule telling it to update the base table instead. It doesn't sound like you've created a rule yet. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules-update.html

Comment: I created a rule. But, I need to run a function result of with will be returned inside an insert rule.